# Android why does this NOT throw wrong thread exception?

Tags: android, multithreading

I was under the impression that views can only be manipulated from the main thread... however, why does this NOT crash:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("original text");
        setContentView(tv);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("trollollolol i should die here but i won't.");
            }
        }).start();        
    }
}
```

i ran on device & emulator, both work just fine and i see the text change. what's going on?

i also checked thread IDs and the background thread is DEFINITELY not the main thread (threadID = 1)

Comment: While I am not too familiar with Android UI -thread implementation and checks - I can't help wondering is there such a thing as "running UI thread" during call to Activity.onCreate? Adding a short Thread.sleep into this Thread crashes the app as expected after all.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the particular implementation of checks either (i've definitely seen some CalledFromWrongThreadException happen before). but by running on UI Thread, i assumed Android perhaps may have had some check for calls to check that your current Thread ID is not 1 or something. thread ID 1 has always been the "main/UI thread" from what i understand

Comment: This is pretty interesting I believe: Add a `Thread.sleep(1000);` inside the thread, before updating the text view. The application will crash and the expected `CalledFromWrongThreadException` is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't actually stop you from updating the UI from outside the main thread. It's just more of a ticking time bomb. If the main UI thread isn't updating the UI at the time, then your thread can do it. 
At least that was my understanding. I don't 100% know for sure, but I've been able to (accidentally) update the UI from outside the main UI thread before. Sometimes it would work and sometimes it wouldn't. But as a good practice i would use a `Async task`.

Comment: FYI: you don't need a `Async task` you could just use `runOnUiThread(Runnable)` from within the other thread. But sometimes `Async` is indeed more useful for real background work.

Comment: I know that. Async Task is just the preferred way.